# Why doesn't certbot-dns-cloudflare plugin install under aws linux

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloudflare, archlinux, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, certbot

I have an elastic beanstalk with a single ec2 instance and I need to install an SSL certificate during deployment and at this time the server can't be reached via the ip address given by the A record on the DNS. I would like to use LetsEncrypt with the certbot-dns-cloudflare plugin to automatically get and install a certificate. I have created a cloudflare credentials file containing my cloudflare api key so that the plugin can request cloudflare to create a DNS TXT record and use it to do the domain name ownership validation.

I encountered a number of problems when attempting to install certbot using the method described here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/SSL-on-an-instance.html#letsencrypt (EPEL libraries not containing certbot), and appeared to have better luck using the cerbot-auto install method here https://medium.com/@mohan08p/install-and-renew-lets-encrypt-ssl-on-amazon-ami-6d3e0a61693.

So my process so far is:

```
$ wget https://dl.eff.org/certbot-auto
$ chmod a+x certbot-auto
$ sudo ./certbot-auto --debug --install-only
```

This appears to get certbot installed and I see no error messages.
Next I do this:

```
$ cd /opt/eff.org/certbot/venv
$ source bin/activate
$ sudo pip install certbot-dns-cloudflare    

    ... cut short for brevity ...
    Collecting zope.event (from zope.component->certbot>=0.21.1->certbot-dns-cloudflare)
      Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/c5/96/361edb421a077a4c208b4a5c212737d78ae03ce67fbbcd01621c49f332d1/zope.event-4.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl
    Collecting pycparser (from cffi!=1.11.3,>=1.7->cryptography>=0.8->acme>=0.21.1->certbot-dns-cloudflare)
      Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/68/9e/49196946aee219aead1290e00d1e7fdeab8567783e83e1b9ab5585e6206a/pycparser-2.19.tar.gz (158kB)
        100% |################################| 163kB 7.9MB/s
    Collecting zope.proxy (from zope.deferredimport>=4.2.1->zope.component->certbot>=0.21.1->certbot-dns-cloudflare)
      Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/7c/f5/e9ed65cdf8c93d24d7512ef89e21b241bc9ae75d90bc8608cc142f4c26f9/zope.proxy-4.3.1.tar.gz (43kB)
        100% |################################| 51kB 12.1MB/s
    Installing collected packages: funcsigs, pbr, six, mock, zope.interface, chardet, idna, certifi, urllib3, asn1crypto, enum34, pycparser, cffi, ipaddress, cryptography, PyOpenSSL, requests, requests-toolbelt, pytz, pyrfc3339, josepy, acme, future, parsedatetime, ConfigArgParse, zope.hookable, zope.proxy, zope.deferredimport, zope.deprecation, zope.event, zope.component, certbot, jsonlines, cloudflare, certbot-dns-cloudflare
      Found existing installation: six 1.8.0
        Uninstalling six-1.8.0:
          Successfully uninstalled six-1.8.0
      Found existing installation: chardet 2.0.1
        DEPRECATION: Uninstalling a distutils installed project (chardet) has been deprecated and will be removed in a future version. This is due to the fact that uninstalling a distutils project will only partially uninstall the project.
        Uninstalling chardet-2.0.1:
          Successfully uninstalled chardet-2.0.1
      Found existing installation: urllib3 1.8.2
        Uninstalling urllib3-1.8.2:
          Successfully uninstalled urllib3-1.8.2
      Running setup.py install for pycparser ... done
      Found existing installation: requests 1.2.3
        Uninstalling requests-1.2.3:
          Successfully uninstalled requests-1.2.3
      Running setup.py install for future ... done
      Running setup.py install for ConfigArgParse ... done
      Running setup.py install for zope.hookable ... done
      Running setup.py install for zope.proxy ... done
      Running setup.py install for cloudflare ... done
    Successfully installed ConfigArgParse-0.13.0 PyOpenSSL-18.0.0 acme-0.29.1 asn1crypto-0.24.0 certbot-0.29.1 certbot-dns-cloudflare-0.29.1 certifi-2018.11.29 cffi-1.11.5 chardet-3.0.4 cloudflare-2.1.0 cryptography-2.4.2 enum34-1.1.6 funcsigs-1.0.2 future-0.17.1 idna-2.8 ipaddress-1.0.22 josepy-1.1.0 jsonlines-1.2.0 mock-2.0.0 parsedatetime-2.4 pbr-5.1.1 pycparser-2.19 pyrfc3339-1.1 pytz-2018.7 requests-2.21.0 requests-toolbelt-0.8.0 six-1.12.0 urllib3-1.24.1 zope.component-4.5 zope.deferredimport-4.3 zope.deprecation-4.4.0 zope.event-4.4 zope.hookable-4.2.0 zope.interface-4.6.0 zope.proxy-4.3.1
    You are using pip version 9.0.3, however version 18.1 is available.
    You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

In the listing I see indications that the cloudflare plugin was successfully installed. However, when I list the plugins I don't see it:

```
$ sudo ./certbot-auto plugins
Saving debug log to /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log

- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
* apache
Description: Apache Web Server plugin
Interfaces: IAuthenticator, IInstaller, IPlugin
Entry point: apache = certbot_apache.entrypoint:ENTRYPOINT

* nginx
Description: Nginx Web Server plugin
Interfaces: IAuthenticator, IInstaller, IPlugin
Entry point: nginx = certbot_nginx.configurator:NginxConfigurator

* standalone
Description: Spin up a temporary webserver
Interfaces: IAuthenticator, IPlugin
Entry point: standalone = certbot.plugins.standalone:Authenticator

* webroot
Description: Place files in webroot directory
Interfaces: IAuthenticator, IPlugin
Entry point: webroot = certbot.plugins.webroot:Authenticator
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
```

Attempts to run certbot-auto using the plugin fail as follows:

```
    $ sudo ./certbot-auto certonly --dns-cloudflare --dns-cloudflare-credentials ~/.secrets/certbot/cloudflare.ini --dns-cloudflare-propagation-seconds 60 -d my-domain.com
usage:
  certbot-auto [SUBCOMMAND] [options] [-d DOMAIN] [-d DOMAIN] ...

Certbot can obtain and install HTTPS/TLS/SSL certificates.  By default,
it will attempt to use a webserver both for obtaining and installing the
certificate.
certbot: error: unrecognized arguments: --dns-cloudflare-credentials /home/ec2-user/.secrets/certbot/cloudflare.ini --dns-cloudflare-propagation-seconds 60
```

Can anyone advise?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what worked for me in the end:

```
$ wget https://dl.eff.org/certbot-auto
$ chmod a+x certbot-auto

$ sudo ./certbot-auto --debug --install-only
$ whereis certbot
certbot: /usr/local/bin/certbot

$ cd /opt/eff.org/certbot/venv
$ source bin/activate
$ sudo pip install certbot-dns-cloudflare
$ deactivate

$ sudo /usr/local/bin/certbot plugins
Saving debug log to /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log

- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
* dns-cloudflare
Description: Obtain certificates using a DNS TXT record (if you are using
Cloudflare for DNS).
Interfaces: IAuthenticator, IPlugin
Entry point: dns-cloudflare =
certbot_dns_cloudflare.dns_cloudflare:Authenticator

* standalone
Description: Spin up a temporary webserver
Interfaces: IAuthenticator, IPlugin
Entry point: standalone = certbot.plugins.standalone:Authenticator

* webroot
Description: Place files in webroot directory
Interfaces: IAuthenticator, IPlugin
Entry point: webroot = certbot.plugins.webroot:Authenticator
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
```

If incorporating this in .ebextensions/01-packages/install-packages.conf which will be run under root, you'll need to add something to create the following file containing your cloudflare email and api key at /root/.secrets/certbot/cloudflare.ini

```
$ sudo mkdir /root/.secrets/certbot
$ sudo chmod 700 /.secrets
$ sudo su

# printf 'dns_cloudflare_email = <your-cf-email>\ndns_cloudflare_api_key = <your-cf-api-key' >  /root/.secrets/certbot/cloudflare.ini 


# printf 'A\nn\nn\n' | /usr/local/bin/certbot certonly --dns-cloudflare --dns-cloudflare-credentials ~/.secrets/certbot/cloudflare.ini --dns-cloudflare-propagation-seconds 60 -d my-domain.com
Saving debug log to /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log
Plugins selected: Authenticator dns-cloudflare, Installer None
Obtaining a new certificate
Performing the following challenges:
dns-01 challenge for my-domain.com
Waiting 60 seconds for DNS changes to propagate
Waiting for verification...
Cleaning up challenges

IMPORTANT NOTES:
 - Congratulations! Your certificate and chain have been saved at:
   /etc/letsencrypt/live/my-domain.com/fullchain.pem
   Your key file has been saved at:
   /etc/letsencrypt/live/my-domain.com/privkey.pem
   Your cert will expire on 2019-03-17. To obtain a new or tweaked
   version of this certificate in the future, simply run certbot
   again. To non-interactively renew *all* of your certificates, run
   "certbot renew"
 - If you like Certbot, please consider supporting our work by:

   Donating to ISRG / Let's Encrypt:   https://letsencrypt.org/donate
   Donating to EFF:                    https://eff.org/donate-le
```

Comment: This was also extremely helpful for installing certbot in a Docker container.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue trying to install cerbot cloudflare plugin on Amazon Linux. I tried a few different things but the following worked using [pip](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/) i.e.

```sh
sudo yum install -y python-pip
pip install --upgrade pip
pip install certbot-dns-cloudflare
```

Answer (score 0):

For me certbot was installed in two locations `/usr/local/bin/certbot` which worked and the default `/usr/bin/certbot` which couldn't find the newly installed plugins.

I was using `which certbot`, `certbot plugins`, and `/usr/local/bin/certbot plugins` to debug this.

Hope this helps someone.